# Why are the buttons on the profile so cramped when editing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

If you edit your user profile, you notice that the buttons are really cramped together, as shown in the picture below. The way I see it, we can fix it by either spacing them out more or by having a separator in between them.

[image: Go to your user profile, then press edit. The options (ex. edit privileges flair my apps) are really cramped together.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `div#mainbar-full` was missing the `.user-show-new` class.

Fixed in next build (`2014.9.22.2591` on meta and `2014.9.22.1881` on sites).